# how to make this circles?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles, venn-diagrams

I would like to make in LaTeX these circles.[image]

How can we add the words in them? The color for the big one?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: They aren't circles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You tagged [tikz-pgf](/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf), so here goes.

The `shadings` library is used to shade the ring similar to your image. The `even odd rule` makes it possible to use another `circle` to not-fill the inner part.

As both circular paths use different line option (one is blue-ish, the other is one black) we cannot use the same `\path` (implicitly called by `\shade`) but use two separate `\draw` commands. For maintainability reasons the path is saved as an `insert path` style so that one can use it again without repeating all values.

The `decorations.text` library is used to place the text along `arc` paths.

A node is placed on the outer circle by

```
\node[dot] at (30:2.5cm and 1.75cm) {};
```

Sadly, one cannot place a node on a `circle` path. There does not even exist a timer. (I think, recent CVS version of PGF allow it to place nodes along an `arc`.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,shadings}
\tikzset{
  saveuse path/.code 2 args={
    \pgfkeysalso{#1/.estyle={insert path={#2}}}%
    \global\expandafter\let\csname pgfk@\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd\expandafter\endcsname % not optimal as it is now global through out the document
                           \csname pgfk@\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd\endcsname
    \pgfkeysalso{#1}%
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[even odd rule,dot/.style={shape=circle,fill=green,draw}]
 \shade[top color=white, bottom color=blue!40] [saveuse path={big circle}  {(0,0) circle [x radius=2.5cm, y radius=1.75cm]}]
                                               [saveuse path={small circle}{(0,0) circle [x radius=1.5cm, y radius=1.0cm]}];

 \draw          [small circle];
 \draw[blue!40] [big circle];

 \node[dot] at (30:2.5cm and 1.75cm) {};
 \path [
   decoration={
     name=text along path,
     text={|\bfseries\sffamily|Productivity||},
     reverse path,
     text align={align=center},
   },
   decorate
 ] (60:2.0cm and 1.4cm) arc [x radius=2.0cm, y radius=1.0cm, start angle=60, end angle=120];

 \path [
   decoration={
     name=text along path,
     text={Efficiency},
     text align={align=center},
   },
   decorate
 ] (-140:1.3cm and .8cm) arc [x radius=1.3cm, y radius=0.5cm, start angle=-140, end angle=-40];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but I would like to ask, if the grid could be erased?

Comment: @giannis Yes, of course. Just remove the `backgrounds` library and the `gridded` option from the TikZ picture.

Comment: Also, how could we add a point in the Big circle?

Comment: @giannis What do you mean? The big circle’s coordinate are accessible with `(<angle>:2.5cm and 1.75cm)`. You can place anything you want on it.

Comment: If I would like to node a dot my code would be: \shade[top color=blue!20, bottom color=blue!20] [saveuse path={big circle}{(0,0) circle [x radius=2.5cm, y radius=1.75cm] node[dot] [x radius=2.8cm, y radius=1.9cm]}]?

Comment: @giannis That doesn’t look right. The `x radius` and `y radius` option do not have anything to do with the `node` and you’re missing at least the `{}` of the node. I wouldn’t include the node in the `saveuse path` either because it would be repeated for the `\draw` part. Let me update the answer with some ideas.