# This elliptical-orbit diagram compiled fine with TikZ 2.10 but fails with TikZ 3.0. Why?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, incompatibility, dimensions

I borrowed some code on [Kepler's 2nd Law](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122122/best-way-to-illustrate-keplers-2nd-law-with-tikz) from the linked post here on TeX answered by Tosco. I haven't compiled the document it is in awhile but needed today. When I did, I was told dimension too large. The dimension too large points to the following lines:

```
% \draw[very thin,->](\oldx,\ol dy)--++(\forcex,\forcey);
\ifnumgreater{(\n - \startone) * (\endone - \n)}{-1}
```

Prior to some update(not sure which one broke it), this code compiled and worked correctly. Now it doesn't. What can be done about this?

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\gdef\myposx{10.0}
\gdef\myposy{0.0}
\gdef\vx{0.0}
\gdef\vy{4.6}
\gdef\forcefactor{150}
\gdef\deltat{0.025}
\gdef\smallmass{1}
\gdef\startone{100}
\gdef\endone{200}
\gdef\starttwo{1800}
\gdef\endtwo{1900}
\gdef\pathone{}
\gdef\pathtwo{}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = .2]
  \filldraw(0, 0) circle [radius = 0.5cm];
  \foreach \n in {1, ..., 3625}
  {
    \pgfextra{%
      \global\let\oldx\myposx
      \global\let\oldy\myposy
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\currentsquareddistance}{\myposx * \myposx + \myposy *
        \myposy}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\currentforce}{\forcefactor / \currentsquareddistance}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\currentangle}{atan2(\myposx, \myposy)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\currentforcex}{-1 * \currentforce * cos(\currentangle)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\currentforcey}{-1 * \currentforce * sin(\currentangle)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\currentvx}{\vx + \deltat * \currentforcex / \smallmass}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\currentvy}{\vy + \deltat * \currentforcey / \smallmass}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\currentposx}{\myposx + \deltat * \currentvx}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\currentposy}{\myposy + \deltat * \currentvy}
      \global\let\myposx\currentposx
      \global\let\myposy\currentposy
      \global\let\vx\currentvx
      \global\let\vy\currentvy
      \global\let\forcex\currentforcex
      \global\let\forcey\currentforcey
      \global\let\myangle\currentangle
      \ifnumequal{\n}{\startone}{%
        \global\let\startonex\oldx
        \global\let\startoney\oldy
        \xappto{\pathone}{(\oldx, \oldy)}
      }{}
      \ifnumequal{\n}{\starttwo}{%
        \global\let\starttwox\oldx
        \global\let\starttwoy\oldy
        \xappto{\pathtwo}{(\oldx, \oldy)}
      }{}
      \ifnumequal{\n}{\endone}{%
        \global\let\endonex\myposx
        \global\let\endoney\myposy
        \xappto{\pathone}{,(\myposx,\myposy)}
      }{}
      \ifnumequal{\n}{\endtwo}{%
        \global\let\endtwox\myposx
        \global\let\endtwoy\myposy
        \xappto{\pathtwo}{,(\myposx, \myposy)}
      }{}
    }
    % \draw[very thin,->](\oldx,\ol dy)--++(\forcex,\forcey);
    \ifnumgreater{(\n - \startone) * (\endone - \n)}{-1}
    {
      \pgfextra{%
        \xappto{\pathone}{,(\myposx, \myposy)}
      }
    }
    {}
    \ifnumgreater{(\n - \starttwo) * (\endtwo - \n)}{-1}
    {
      \pgfextra{%
        \xappto{\pathtwo}{,(\myposx, \myposy)}
      }
    }
    {}
    \draw(\oldx, \oldy)--(\myposx, \myposy);
  }
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \filldraw[blue, opacity = .5] (0, 0)%
    \foreach \point in \pathone
    {%
      --\point
    }--(0, 0);
    \filldraw[blue, opacity = .5] (0, 0)%
    \foreach \point in \pathtwo
    {%
      --\point
    }--(0, 0);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the syntax of `atan2`, [the two-argument variant of arctangent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Two-argument_variant_of_arctangent), changed between TikZ 2.10 and TikZ 3.0.

The effect of this change of syntax on [Toscho's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122183/21891) makes the trajectory of the orbiting body (an asteroid?) become completely unstable very quickly: the asteroid quickly "shoots off the page". As as a result, the dimension of the resulting diagram rapidly exceeds what TeX can handle (about 19 feet), and TeX complains by issuing `Dimension too large` errors.

Let's examine the description of `atan2` in the v2.10 and v3.0 manuals a bit closer...

### TikZ v2.10, released 2010/12/20 (63.2.3 *Trigonometric functions*)

[image]

### TikZ 3.0, released 2013/12/20 (90.2.4 *Trigonometric functions*)

[image]

### Problem

In both manuals, the inputs in the examples are the same, the syntax is the same... or is it?! As pointed out by percusse in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171713/this-elliptical-orbit-diagram-compiled-fine-with-tikz-2-10-but-fails-with-tikz-3/171736?noredirect=1#comment396474_171736), **the two arguments, `x` and `y`, have been swapped between the two releases**! Therefore, the outputs differ. Those TikZ maintainers sure are sneaky `}:-)`

### Solution

Simply swapping the arguments of `atan2` in your code, i.e. writing

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\currentangle}{atan2(\myposy, \myposx)}
```

instead of

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\currentangle}{atan2(\myposx, \myposy)}
```

produces the correct output, shown below.

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm that the trajectory is supposed to be elliptical with Toscho's values? Maybe the `tikz` maintainers changed the implementation of the `atan2` function and introduced some bug in the process...

Comment: The only difference between what I had and the original was the first filldraw circle and delta t (I took a bigger step).  Changing to Toscho's code still produces the same error as well.

Comment: Notice that the arguments are swapped.

Comment: @percusse You're right! I hadn't noticed it... I'm going to hit the max number of edits before CC wiki quickly on this answer...