# "Stroke" a predefined path

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

I would like to use the name of a previous defined path to draw it later on in my code. I have included an example below, where I define two paths, "D1" and "S1", and then later on, draw these very sames paths. In the example, I draw the paths, using essentially the same code, which is redundant. Is there a way to recall the name of the path and draw a line using the previously defined path?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=3,xscale=3]

%Pre-Define Paths

\path[name path=D1] (0,1.8) -- (1.8,0);
\path[name path=S1] (0,0) -- (1.8,1.8);
\path[name intersections={of=D1 and S1,by=EQ}];

%axis

\draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[right,fontscale=0] {Quantity};
\draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[left,fontscale=0] {Price};

%Initial Equilibrium

\fill[black] (EQ) circle (.5pt) node[right] {$EQ$};
\draw[blue] (0,1.8) -- (1.8,0);
\draw[red] (0,0) -- (1.8,1.8);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the undocumented `save path` key that saves the whole path on a very low level in a macro. You can use this path again with the `use path` key defined as

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{use path/.code=\tikz@addmode{\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath#1}}
\makeatother
```

Any path operators shouldn’t be used here.

If you want to save part of a path and want to use them later (maybe also only as a part), you can use the `saveuse path` key from [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114943/16595) defined as

```
\tikzset{
  saveuse path/.code 2 args={
    \pgfkeysalso{#1/.estyle={insert path={#2}}}%
    \global\expandafter\let\csname pgfk@\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd\expandafter\endcsname % not optimal as it is now global through out the document
                           \csname pgfk@\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd\endcsname
    \pgfkeysalso{#1}%
  }
}
```

The `saveuse path` key saves a path as an `insert path` key (and uses it also) which can be used later for the same path (as long as you don’t change the transformation matrix).

### Code A

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{use path/.code=\tikz@addmode{\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=3,xscale=3]

%Pre-Define Paths
\path[save path=\pathA,name path=D1] (0,1.8) -- (1.8,0);
\path[save path=\pathB,name path=S1] (0,0) -- (1.8,1.8);
\path[name intersections={of=D1 and S1,by=EQ}];

%axis
\draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {Quantity};
\draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[left] {Price};

%Initial Equilibrium
\fill[black] (EQ) circle (.5pt) node[right] {$EQ$};
\draw[blue][use path=\pathA];
\draw[red] [use path=\pathB];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code B

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\tikzset{
  saveuse path/.code 2 args={
    \pgfkeysalso{#1/.estyle={insert path={#2}}}%
    \global\expandafter\let\csname pgfk@\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd\expandafter\endcsname % not optimal as it is now global through out the document
                           \csname pgfk@\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd\endcsname
    \pgfkeysalso{#1}%
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=3,xscale=3]

%Pre-Define Paths
\path[name path=D1] [saveuse path={pathA}{(0,1.8) -- (1.8,0)}];
\path[name path=S1] [saveuse path={pathB}{(0,0) -- (1.8,1.8)}];
\path[name intersections={of=D1 and S1,by=EQ}];

%axis
\draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {Quantity};
\draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[left] {Price};

%Initial Equilibrium
\fill[black] (EQ) circle (.5pt) node[right] {$EQ$};
\draw[blue][pathA];
\draw[red] [pathB];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. One question: In Code A, I tried to make the "save path" name more intuitive, i.e. \pathD1. This would not compile because of the number "1" in the name. Are there restrictions on the names that can be used with "save path?"

Comment: @stanford202 The same as with every macro name in TeX with the default [tag:catcode] settings. You could use `save path/.expand once=\csname pathD1\endcsname` and `use path=\csname pathD1\endcsname` (or create wrapper macros for `save path` and `use path` that do exactly this: `save path*/.style={save path/.expand once={\csname#1\endcsname}}, use path*/.style={use path={\csname#1\endcsname}}`).

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is to store the path D1 in a variable \D1, and so for S1.
Then use this variable as many times as needed. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d,shapes, pgfplots.external, intersections}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=3,xscale=3]

%Pre-Define Paths

  \def\D1{(0,1.8) -- (1.8,0)}
  \def\S1{(0,0) -- (1.8,1.8)}

\path[name path=D1] \D1;
\path[name path=S1] \S1;
\path[name intersections={of=D1 and S1,by=EQ}];

%axis

\draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {Quantity};
\draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[left] {Price};

%Initial Equilibrium

\fill[black] (EQ) circle (.5pt) node[right] {$EQ$};
\draw[blue] \D1;
\draw[red] \S1;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the figure:

[image]

Comment: Technically speaking you are not saving the path. You are saving the input of the path. If there is a decoration or something similar on the path  this won't work.

Comment: note that the `1` in `\def\D1{...}` is rather acting like a parameter delimeter than part of the control sequence name. If you said `\def\D2{...}` afterwards and then tried to use `\D1` you would get the error `! Use of \D doesn't match its definition.`. Also note that spaces after `\D1` are _not_ ignored. see TeXBook pages 202--204.

Comment: You can probably also use `\newcommand` instead of `\def`.