# How to cross over only at intersections in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-arrows

I'm using `tikzcd` to draw diagrams. I want one line to cross another at (and only at) the intersection. I use the `crossing over` option. But there is something else being covered. Here is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  X_1 &X_2 &X_3\ar[dll]\\
  Y_1 &Y_2 &Y_3
  \ar[from=1-2,crossing over]
  \ar[from=1-1,crossing over]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

The picture is the result. I draw a red cycle manually to emphasize arrow. Part of the head of the arrow from `$X_2$` to `$Y_3$` is covered.
[image]

So, is there some method to make the `crossing over` only at the intersections? Thank you for some suggestions.

Comment: Can you add a complete MWE so I can see your package, please?

Comment: @Sebastiano I just use `tikz-cd`. I complete the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the most elegant solution, but one approach with TikZ.

It draws white circles between the arrow in the background and the arrows in the foreground at the intersections.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,intersections}
\pgfdeclarelayer{fg}
\pgfdeclarelayer{crossing over}
\pgfsetlayers{main,crossing over,fg}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm, circle] {
        X_1 &X_2 &X_3 \\
        Y_1 &Y_2 &Y_3 \\
    };
    \draw[->, name path=bg arrow]  (m-1-3) -- (m-2-1);
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{fg}
        \draw[->, name path global/.expanded=fg arrow1] (m-1-1) -- (m-2-3);
        \draw[->, name path global/.expanded=fg arrow2] (m-1-2) -- (m-2-3);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{crossing over}
        \foreach \arrow in {1, ..., 2} {
            \fill[white, name intersections={of=bg arrow and fg arrow\arrow, name=i}] (i-1) circle (2pt);
        }
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Edit:
Alternative code producing same output but avoiding several layers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,intersections}
\makeatletter
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127045/120953
\tikzset{use path/.code=\tikz@addmode{\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm, circle] {
        X_1 &X_2 &X_3 \\
        Y_1 &Y_2 &Y_3 \\
    };
    \draw[->, name path=bg arrow]  (m-1-3) -- (m-2-1);
    \path[name path=fg arrow1, save path=\pathFGone] (m-1-1) -- (m-2-3);
    \path[name path=fg arrow2, save path=\pathFGtwo] (m-1-2) -- (m-2-3);
    \foreach \arrow in {1, ..., 2} {
        \fill[white, name intersections={of=bg arrow and fg arrow\arrow, name=i}] (i-1) circle (2pt);
    }
    \draw[->, use path=\pathFGone];
    \draw[->, use path=\pathFGtwo];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that the layer `crossing over` covers `main` and `fg` covers `crossing over`. Is it possible to use the cycle built by `\fill` command covers the path from `(m-1-3)` to `(m-2-1)` by changing the order of the commands and without using `pfgonlayer`? It seems that i can draw `(m-1-3)--(m-2-1)` and an empty `(m-1-1)--(m-2-3)`. Then place an empty cycle at the intersection. Then draw a black `(m-1-1)--(m-2-3)`. Then could the `name intersections` compute the intersection of `(m-1-3)--(m-2-1)` and `(m-1-1)--(m-2-3)` before drawing `(m-1-1)--(m-2-3)`?

Comment: @jiaopjie yes, it is possible to avoid `pgfonlayer`. see my edited answer.

Answer (score 5):

I resolve your question reducing the lenght of one arrow from `X_1` to `Y_3`. I hope it goes well. Generally I try change slightly every MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep = large, row sep = large]
  X_1 &X_2 &X_3\ar[dll]\\
  Y_1 &Y_2 &Y_3
  \ar[from=1-2,crossing over]
  \ar[from=1-1,crossing over, shorten >= 5pt]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

One very simple solution is redrawing the first crossing arrow without the `cross over` option.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  X_1 &X_2 &X_3\ar[dll]\\
  Y_1 &Y_2 &Y_3
  \ar[from=1-2,crossing over]
  \ar[from=1-1,crossing over]
  \ar[from=1-2]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

If you don't like how the top of the arrows are arranged you can additionally use [Sebastiano's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353762/143676) and shorten one of the arrows a little bit, e.g., `\ar[from=1-1,crossing over,shorten=2pt]`.