# Tikzcd question on arrows

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I have a (probably easy) question on tikzcd: I want to draw two arrows from bottom to top, intersecting each other and having a label. What I tried so far

```
\begin{tikzcd}

\gamma & \kappa \\
 &  \\
\arrow{uur} &  \arrow{uul}
\end{tikzcd}
```

Which gives

[image]

But this looks not really symmetric. Where is the problem? I also tried to eally use labels on the arows but it was never really clear to see which label belongs to which arrow. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is, related to [How to cross over only at intersections in tikzcd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353762/124842):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep = large, row sep = large]
  \ar[from=2-2]\gamma & \ar[from=2-1]\kappa\\
  \null & \null
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

**EDIT:**
 Related to your comment i added only a workaround with white space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep = large, row sep = large]
  \ar[from=2-2]\gamma & \ar[from=2-1]\kappa\\
  \textcolor{white}{\gamma} & \textcolor{white}{\kappa}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This still looks like the part below the crossing is larger then the part over the crossing...? Do have any solution for that?

Comment: And also the lower part is wider then the upper part

Comment: @ mathstackuser : I updatd my answer. Maybe there is an better option (and someone will help later), but first i added this workaround. Hope it helps.

Comment: @mathstackuser For my opinion the 2th code of the user is very good. +1

Comment: Yes, I like it too! Any ideas for the second picture?

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thank you for the reference to my reply.

Comment: @mathstackuser Excuse me. Can you ask a new question for the 2nd figure please? They are two different question.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I did. Yu can fin it here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/441803/166569