# Arrows with tikzcd

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I would like to draw something like this, preferably with tikzcd.

[image]

Any ideas for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why `tikz-cd`?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,fill,scale=0.3,label=right:$x$] (x1) at (0,0) {};
\node[circle,fill,scale=0.3,label=right:$y$] (y1) at (2,0) {};
\node[circle,fill,scale=0.3,label=left:$x$] (x2) at (4,0) {};
\draw[-latex] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[left,yshift=-1cm]{$\gamma$};
\draw[-latex] (2,-4) -- (2,-0.5) arc(270:90:0.5) -- (2,4)
node[left,yshift=-1cm]{$\gamma'$};
\draw[-latex] (4,-4) -- (4,-0.5) arc(-90:90:0.5) -- (4,4)
node[left,yshift=-1cm]{$\gamma''$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Erh, you're not using tikz-cd in that example, just plain til. Nice solution though

Comment: @daleif I am aware of that, which is why I wrote "Why `tikz-cd`?", and do not see any point in using `tikz-cd` for it (unless there is a bigger picture, which is however not obvious from the question).

Comment: Oh, I misread the op question

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thanks! I suggested tikz-cd because I am more familar with, but that's a great solution