# How do I get this node correctly vertically and horizontally aligned, no deviation horizontally from node above?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, intersections

I am trying to get the node `\node[below = 3 cm of OPC] (NCM) {No match};` aligned so it is directly below the node above, and exactly on the same line as the node to the right. If I do a simple below specification (code not commented out) then it's too low compared to the one on the right, even though I thought they should be the same vertical height as everything is one line. I want to keep the relative positioning.

I know how to position the nodes equidistant when the nodes are on the same vertical level, but I can't work out how to do this when one node is above and the other is on the same line. My attempt is shown commented out. The key problem is that it puts a `)` in the `Couples` node, otherwise it looks good. When I did a toy example, all the nodes were only one line, and there was no problem just using the `below = of` method. Maybe this problem here is due to the multi-line nodes?

Also, is there an easy way to a little arc on the `OPC` to `PCM` nodes? There are some answers using [a matrix layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353759/how-to-cross-over-only-at-intersections-in-tikzcd) and [this uses circles](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/line-junction/), but is there an easier way? The line where I would like to show as an overlap is `\draw[arrow] (node cs:name=RPIC) -- (node cs:name=NCM)`

Code

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[a4paper,layout=a4paper,
        bindingoffset=4cm,left=0cm,right=2cm,
        head=2.5cm, bmargin=2cm]{geometry}      %get the page layout right
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}                        %turn off hypenation globally
\usepackage{microtype}                              %better typesetting, affects justification and punctuation
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}                                    % typeset URL's reasonably
\usepackage[round]{natbib}                          % default bracket type is round
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}                               %typeset tables better
\usepackage{multirow}                               %allow merge look across table rows
%\usepackage{placeins}                              %fix table floats!
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                                 % must be imported BEFORE tikz
\usepackage{tikz}                                   %write flowcharts etc
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, chains, fit, backgrounds, calc, decorations.pathreplacing, matrix, calligraphy, positioning}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}   

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style= {draw, rounded corners, font=\footnotesize, align=center}, 
arrow/.style={thick, -stealth}]
\node (CPL) {Couples};
\node[right = 6cm of CPL] (Ch) {Children};

\node[below left = 3cm and 0cm of CPL] (OPC) {Other person\\in couple};
\node[below right = 3cm and 0cm of CPL] (RPIC) {Reference person\\in couple} ;
\node[below left = 3cm and 0cm of Ch] (CFC) {Children\\for couples};
\node[below right = 3cm and 0cm of Ch] (CFSP) {Children for\\sole-parents};

%   \node[below = 3 cm of $(OPC)(RPIC)$] (NCM) {No child match};
\node[below = 3 cm of OPC] (NCM) {No child match};
\node[below = 3 cm of $(RPIC)!0.5!(CFC)$] (PCM) {Parent-child match};
%   \node[below = 3 cm of $(CFSP)(PCM)$] (TNF) {\Cref{fig:SPWC}};

\draw[arrow] (node cs:name=CPL) -- (node cs:name=OPC);
\draw[arrow] (node cs:name=CPL) -- (node cs:name=RPIC);
\draw[arrow] (node cs:name=Ch) -- (node cs:name=CFC);
\draw[arrow] (node cs:name=Ch) -- (node cs:name=CFSP);
%   \draw[arrow] (node cs:name=OPC) -- (node cs:name=NCM);
%   \draw[arrow] (node cs:name=RPIC) -- (node cs:name=NCM);
\draw[arrow] (node cs:name=OPC) -- (node cs:name=PCM);
\draw[arrow] (node cs:name=RPIC) -- (node cs:name=PCM);
\draw[arrow] (node cs:name=CFC) -- (node cs:name=PCM);
%   \draw[arrow] (node cs:name=CFSP) -- (node cs:name=TNF);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: add `(OPC|-PCM)` is the `intersection` of the `vertical line down from OPC` and `horizontal line from PCM`

Comment: for the problem of different height of node `CPl` and node `Ch` due to `descenders like p` use `minimum height` in the definition of the node -- this can be also used for multi line nodes to give consistent shapes

Comment: for the problem of an arrow from node RPIC to NCM you could use a different colored arrow such as  --   `\draw[arrow, blue] (RPIC) -- (NCM);`

Comment: Thanks, just changed the name of the nodes there, forgot I had started writing the question with the toy example (which didn't have the problem!) in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[a4paper,layout=a4paper,
        bindingoffset=4cm,left=0cm,right=2cm,
        head=2.5cm, bmargin=2cm]{geometry}      %get the page layout right
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}                        %turn off hypenation globally
\usepackage{microtype}                              %better typesetting, affects justification and punctuation
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}                                    % typeset URL's reasonably
\usepackage[round]{natbib}                          % default bracket type is round
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}                               %typeset tables better
\usepackage{multirow}                               %allow merge look across table rows
%\usepackage{placeins}                              %fix table floats!
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                                 % must be imported BEFORE tikz
\usepackage{tikz}                                   %write flowcharts etc
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, chains, fit, backgrounds, calc, decorations.pathreplacing, matrix, calligraphy, positioning}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}   

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style= {draw, rounded corners, font=\footnotesize, align=center, minimum height=0.8cm}, 
arrow/.style={thick, -stealth}]
\node (CPL) {Couples};
\node[right = 6cm of CPL] (Ch) {Children};

\node[below left = 2cm and 0cm of CPL] (OPC) {Other person\\in couple};
\node[below left = 2cm and 0cm of Ch] (CFC) {Children\\for couples};
\node[below right = 2cm and 0cm of Ch] (CFSP) {Children for\\sole-parents};
\node[below right = 2cm and 0cm of CPL] (RPIC) {Reference person\\in couple} ;

%   \node[below = 3 cm of $(OPC)(RPIC)$] (NCM) {No child match};
\node[below = 2 cm of $(RPIC)!0.5!(CFC)$]  (PCM) {Parent-child match};
\node at (OPC|-PCM) (NCM) {No child match};
\draw [red] (NCM.south) -- (PCM.south);
%   \node[below = 3 cm of $(CFSP)(PCM)$] (TNF) {\Cref{fig:SPWC}};

\draw[arrow] (CPL) -- (OPC);
\draw[arrow] (CPL) -- (RPIC);
\draw[arrow] (Ch) -- (CFC);
\draw[arrow] (Ch) -- (CFSP);
%   \draw[arrow] (node cs:name=OPC) -- (node cs:name=NCM);
%   \draw[arrow] (node cs:name=RPIC) -- (node cs:name=NCM);
\draw[arrow] (OPC) -- (PCM);
\draw[arrow] (RPIC) -- (PCM);
\draw[arrow] (CFC) -- (PCM);
%   \draw[arrow] (node cs:name=CFSP) -- (node cs:name=TNF);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was having major latex issues and couldn't typeset until just now.