# Drawing cubes with crossing overs

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, xymatrix

I would like to draw the following picture with the dashed arrows replaced by the crossing overs in xymatrix or in tikz. I drew this one tikz but somehow unable to do the crossing overs.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
\begin{figure}[hbt]
 \centering
 \scalebox{0.6}
 {
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
     \tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]
     \tikzstyle{selected vertex} = [vertex, fill=blue!24]
     \tikzstyle{selected edge} = [draw,line width=1pt,-,blue!50]
     \tikzstyle{edge} = [draw,line width=3pt,-,white]
     \node[vertex] (v1) at (0,2) {$K(V,0)$};
     \node[vertex] (v2) at (1, 2) {$\binom{V_1}{V}$};
     \node[vertex] (v3) at (0.33, 1.66) {$\binom{V_2}{V}$};
      \node[vertex] (v4) at (0,1) {$\binom{V_3}{V}$};
         \node[vertex] (v5) at (0.33,0.66) {${\begin{psmallmatrix} V_{23}\\
      V_2\oplus V_3\\ V
  \end{psmallmatrix}}$};
     \node[vertex] (v6) at (1,1) {${\begin{psmallmatrix} V_{13}\\
      V_1\oplus V_3\\ V
  \end{psmallmatrix}}$};
     \node[vertex] (v7) at (1.33, 0.66) {${\begin{psmallmatrix} V_{12}\oplus V_{13}\oplus V_{23}\\
      V_1\oplus V_2 \oplus V_3\\ V
  \end{psmallmatrix}}$};
     \node[vertex] (v8) at (1.33, 1.66) {${\begin{psmallmatrix} V_{12}\\
      V_1\oplus V_2\\ V
  \end{psmallmatrix}}$};
         \node[vertex] (v9) at (0.7, 1.8) {$\binom{V_1\oplus V_2}{V}$};
\node[vertex] (v10) at (0.6,1.2) {$\binom{V_1\oplus V_3}{V}$};
\node[vertex] (v11) at (0.17,1.23) {$\binom{V_2\oplus V_3}{V}$};
    
    \draw[-to] (v1) -- (v2);
    \draw[-to] (v1) -- (v3);
    \draw[-to] (v1) -- (v4);
    \draw[-to] (v2) -- (v8);
    %\draw[edge] (v2)--(v6);
    \draw[dashed, -to] (v2) -- (v6);
     \draw[-to] (v3) -- (v8);
     \draw[dashed, -to] (v4) -- (v6);
     \draw[-to] (v4) -- (v5);
     \draw[-to] (v8) -- (v7);
     \draw[-to] (v3) -- (v5);
     \draw[-to] (v5) -- (v7);
     \draw[dashed, -to] (v6) -- (v7);
     \draw[-to] (v2) -- (v9);
     \draw[-to] (v3) -- (v9);
     \draw[->] (v9) -- (v8);
     \draw[dashed,->] (v2) -- (v10);
     \draw[dashed,->] (v4) -- (v10);
     \draw[dashed, ->] (v10) -- (v6);
     \draw[->] (v3) -- (v11);
     \draw[->] (v4) -- (v11);
     \draw[->] (v11) -- (v5);
\end{tikzpicture}
 }
 \end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Please try to compile your posted code in a fresh file ... and add the missing codelines for us. Thank you

Comment: What does "crossing over" mean? What style do you intend the arrows to have?

Comment: @JasperHabicht presumably that at a crossing one of the arrows has a hole the other goes through.

Comment: @daleif maybe, but there are also other ways, like a bump ...

Comment: Did you use the/a help grid and/or polar coordinates to place nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it. Without being able to compile your code I assume you face 3 problems:

- structure/placement of nodes
- replacement of node content
- adjustments

#### 1. Placement of nodes

There are several ways to specify the nodes coordinates, like:

- cartesian coordinates
- polar coordinates
- matrix (the Tikz equivalent of a table)
- etc.

I take the matrix-route here. So all I need to do is to perceive the positions as rows and columns. To better keep track I put node-coordinates in red in this sketch, and rows and columns in blue:

[image: sketch]

So `Part 1` in the code below just does that:

- placing such nodes
- connecting them by two types of styles

Don't worry too much about proportions and sizes, as this can still all be adjusted. Kindly watch the x-shift I used for D3 for that purpose. However, I'd delay that to the last step.

Row `\node {\strut}; & & & & & & \\` just functions as a placeholder to give some more vertical space.

[image: placements]

#### 2. Replacement of contents (Part 2)

I just show the beginning of this process, replacing some of your content in math-mode.

To better assist the illusion of placing the diagonal nodes, I made the line thickness of the outer ones thicker, see style-statements.

If you don't like the separation of nodes D2 and D3, write them in one row (i.e. delete the excessive one), and perhaps apply some yshift as needed, later.

[image: replacement started]

#### 3. Adjustments

So the major adjustment to make will be here for the row and column separations, and perhaps a few shifts you applied where needed:

```
  \matrix[column sep=6mm, row sep=6mm]
```

#### Suggested tactics

- draw this cube with the `standalone` class
- compile it and use `\includegraphics` for the pdf from the `graphicx` package in your main document

#### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
 % ~~~ developing the structure ~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    vs/.style={->, dashed},
    >={Stealth},
 ]
 % ~~~ Part 1: placement ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \matrix[column sep=20mm, row sep=12mm]
  {
    \node (100) {100}; & & & & \node (110) {110}; & & \\
     & & & \node(D1) {D1}; & & \\
     & & \node (101) {101}; & & & & \node (111) {111}; \\
     & &  \node[xshift=9mm] (D3) {D3}; & & &\\
     & \node (D2) {D2}; \\
    \node (000) {000};&  & & & \node (010) {010}; & & \\
    \node {\strut}; & & & & & & \\
     & & \node (001) {001}; & & & & \node (011) {011}; \\
  };
  % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~
  %     top
  \draw[->] (100) -- (110);
  \draw[->] (100) -- (101);
  \draw[->] (101) -- (111);
  \draw[->] (110) -- (111);
    
  %     down
  \draw[->] (100) -- (000);
  \draw[->] (101) -- (001);
  \draw[->] (111) -- (011);
  \draw[vs] (110) -- (010);
  
  %     side
  \draw[->] (000) -- (001);
  \draw[vs] (010) -- (011);
  \draw[->] (101) -- (D2);
  \draw[->] (000) -- (D2);
  \draw[->] (D2) -- (001);
  
  %     bottom
  \draw[vs] (000) -- (010);
  \draw[->] (001) -- (011);
  
  %     diagonals
  \draw[->] (101) -- (D1);
  \draw[->] (110) -- (D1);
  \draw[->] (D1) -- (111);
  \draw[vs] (110) -- (D3);
  \draw[vs] (000) -- (D3);
  \draw[vs] (D3) -- (010);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
 % ~~~ Part 2: replacements ~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    vs/.style={->, dashed},
    vt/.style={->, line width=1.5pt},
    >={Stealth},
 ]
 % ~~~ placement ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \matrix[column sep=6mm, row sep=6mm]
  {
    \node (100) {$K(V,0)$}; & & & & 
    \node (110) {$\binom{V_1}{V}$}; & & \\
     & & & \node(D1) {$\binom{V_1\oplus V_2}{V}$}; & & \\
     & & \node (101) {$\binom{V_2}{V}$}; & & & & & 
     \node (111) {111}; \\
     & &  \node[xshift=9mm] (D3) {D3}; & & &\\
     & \node (D2) {D2}; \\
    \node (000) {000};&  & & & \node (010) {010}; & & \\
    \node {\strut}; & & & & & & \\
     & & \node (001) {001}; & & & & & \node (011) {011}; \\
  };
  % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~
  %     top
  \draw[vt] (100) -- (110);
  \draw[vt] (100) -- (101);
  \draw[vt] (101) -- (111);
  \draw[vt] (110) -- (111);
    
  %     down
  \draw[->] (100) -- (000);
  \draw[->] (101) -- (001);
  \draw[->] (111) -- (011);
  \draw[vs] (110) -- (010);
  
  %     side
  \draw[->] (000) -- (001);
  \draw[vs] (010) -- (011);
  \draw[->] (101) -- (D2);
  \draw[->] (000) -- (D2);
  \draw[->] (D2) -- (001);
  
  %     bottom
  \draw[vs] (000) -- (010);
  \draw[->] (001) -- (011);
  
  %     diagonals
  \draw[->] (101) -- (D1);
  \draw[->] (110) -- (D1);
  \draw[->] (D1) -- (111);
  \draw[vs] (110) -- (D3);
  \draw[vs] (000) -- (D3);
  \draw[vs] (D3) -- (010);
 \end{tikzpicture}  
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I want a crossing-over arrow instead of the dashed one. Here is one example of crossing over arrows https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353759/how-to-cross-over-only-at-intersections-in-tikzcd

Comment: Please see my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701981/245790, and my suggestion: don't do it with this visual effect ...

Answer (score 1):

Follow-up to [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701915/245790) ; not intended for voting, but to keep a long answer more readable.

Here's one way to do it with plain `Tikz`. **However**, I suggest to rethink your crossing-over idea, which is just a visual means, requiring quite some effort with many side effects.

#### Basic idea

- once everything else has been drawn
- draw the cross-over-pathes at the end
- so their white large outlines cover the rest
- giving the illusion of "crossing"

This brings some problems with it. Let's see.

[image: result]

#### Style

The new style `co` uses the `double` parameters of a path, see Ch. 15 in the pgfmanual.

```
 % ~~~ Part 3: crossing over  ~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    vs/.style={->, dashed},
    vt/.style={->, line width=1.5pt},
    >={Stealth},
    % to cross over:
    co/.style={
        % double line parameters:   
        draw=white,double=black,line width=3pt,
        double distance=1.5pt,
        % arrow-tip parameters
        -{Stealth[width=10mm,fill=black]}},
 ]
```

For better visibility I changed one line to blue on the right side.

As described there it:

- draws a thick line, including arrows, here in white
- draws the "normal" line, here in black

There's a trade-off from contradicting requirements:

- you want a thick white line to "cover/cross" others
- you want a thin white line to avoid other obscuring artifacts

See the thick front line to 111: the thick white outline of the arrow tip obscures other lines, including the tip. You can balance the `co`-parameters to some extent ...

#### Drawing last pathes

Here you see a few approaches combined:

- first the line to 111 at the top
- second, a nodes place held being overdrawn
- third, the blue line at the side with a different approach

```
  %     crossing over pathes
  %  front, top
  \draw[vt,co] (101) -- (111);
  %  drawing over the placeholder
  \node[fill=white] at (D1) {$\binom{V_1\oplus V_2}{V}$};
  % alternative: draw thick white line AND normal vector
  \draw[draw=white, line width=12pt] (D2) -- (001);
  \draw[->,blue] (D2) -- (001);
```

The first one I just described.

The second one would "overwrite" the arrows behind (D1) at the top. Two steps:

- put a big enough empty node into the matrix (code next)
- put a second node at its place at the end (code before)

```
%    & & & \node(D1) {$\binom{V_1\oplus V_2}{V}$}; & & \\
%    new: placeholder
     & & & \node[minimum size=10mm] (D1) {}; & & \\
```

The third just draws a connection twice:

- once as a big white line without arrow tip
- and as an ordinary vector
- kindly recognise the artifacts near 001

#### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
 % ~~~ developing the structure ~~~~~~~~~

 % ~~~ Part 3: crossing over  ~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    vs/.style={->, dashed},
    vt/.style={->, line width=1.5pt},
    >={Stealth},
    % to cross over:
    co/.style={
        % double line parameters:   
        draw=white,double=black,line width=3pt,
        double distance=1.5pt,
        % arrow-tip parameters
        -{Stealth[width=10mm,fill=black]}},
 ]
 % ~~~ placement ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \matrix[column sep=6mm, row sep=6mm]
  {
    \node (100) {$K(V,0)$}; & & & & 
    \node (110) {$\binom{V_1}{V}$}; & & \\
%    & & & \node(D1) {$\binom{V_1\oplus V_2}{V}$}; & & \\
%    new: placeholder
     & & & \node[minimum size=10mm] (D1) {}; & & \\
     & & \node (101) {$\binom{V_2}{V}$}; & & & & & 
     \node (111) {111}; \\
     & &  \node[xshift=9mm] (D3) {D3}; & & &\\
     & \node (D2) {D2}; \\
    \node (000) {000};&  & & & \node (010) {010}; & & \\
    \node {\strut}; & & & & & & \\
     & & \node (001) {001}; & & & & & \node (011) {011}; \\
  };
  % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~
  %     top
  \draw[vt] (100) -- (110);
  \draw[vt] (100) -- (101);

  \draw[vt] (110) -- (111);    
  %     down
  \draw[->] (100) -- (000);
  \draw[->] (101) -- (001);
  \draw[->] (111) -- (011);
  % highlighting this one: remove the dashed parameter
  \draw[->,blue] (110) -- (010);% <<< new
  
  %     side
  \draw[->] (000) -- (001);
  \draw[vs] (010) -- (011);
  \draw[->] (101) -- (D2);
  \draw[->] (000) -- (D2);
%  \draw[->] (D2) -- (001);
  
  %     bottom
  \draw[vs] (000) -- (010);
  \draw[->] (001) -- (011);
  
  %     diagonals
  \draw[->] (101) -- (D1);
  \draw[->] (110) -- (D1);
  \draw[->] (D1) -- (111);
  \draw[vs] (110) -- (D3);
  \draw[vs] (000) -- (D3);
  \draw[vs] (D3) -- (010);
  
  %     crossing over pathes
  %  front, top
  \draw[vt,co] (101) -- (111);
  %  drawing over the placeholder
  \node[fill=white] at (D1) {$\binom{V_1\oplus V_2}{V}$};
  % alternative: draw thick white line AND normal vector
  \draw[draw=white, line width=12pt] (D2) -- (001);
  \draw[->,blue] (D2) -- (001);

 \end{tikzpicture}  
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this amazing help. One more small issue. Can we resize this diagram? I usually write \begin{figure}[hbt]
 \centering
 \scalebox{0.6}
 {
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]

Comment: But in this case it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

As follow up to [your comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701895/drawing-cubes-with-crossing-overs/701915?noredirect=1#comment1746002_701981), which is quite unspecific, and this answer being a separate issue.

#### Background

There are several ways to use `Tikz drawings`, like:

- writing code directly into your document (like you seem to do)
- moving `Tikz-code` to an external file and `\input` it (which is basically the same)
- using package `subfiles`, which allows separate compilation of each subfile AND the main document
- **my proposal**: using package `graphicx`
- and certainly more ways to do it

With Tikz code in your main document you probably missed `transform shape` in your options; see the pgfmanual.

#### Example

- first create AND compile your Tikz drawing in a separate file, using class `standalone`
- second, include the pdf as graphics

To do so:

- make the `standalone` drawing look right
- i.e. adjust `column sep`, `row sep` and node `shifts` as needed
- tune for a balanced look first

When including a pdf via `graphicx` it still remains a vector graphics, i.e. you don't have pixel artifacts, unless your pdf-viewer introduces them.

#### Result and code

Assuming `cubeCross.pdf` as standalone file, in teh same directory, from class `standalone` [from my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701981/245790):

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[10]
    
    For including the Tikz-drawing see figure \ref{img}.    
    
 \begin{figure}[!h]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{cubeCross}
    \caption{Including cubeCross.pdf}\label{img}
 \end{figure}   
    
    \lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```