# Drawing lines and curves from their central/middle points

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use the following code to draw lines from their central points, to facilitate their positioning in relation to each other.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,4);
\draw [thick, green] (1.8,1.4) node [circle, draw, black, fill=black, scale=0.2]{} +(-50:1.4cm) -- +(130:1.4cm);
\draw [thick, orange] (1.4,1.4) node [circle, draw, black, fill=black, scale=0.2]{} +(50:1.4cm) -- +(-130:1.4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Using the following code, is there a way to draw curves also from their middle points.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,4);
\draw [thick, green] (.88,3.5) to [out=-90,in=180] node [pos=.5,circle, draw, red, fill=red, scale=0.2]{} +(-46.:4.cm);
\draw [thick, blue] (.74,.2) to [out=90,in=-90] node [pos=.5,circle, draw, red, fill=red, scale=0.2]{} +(60:3.8cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly not a complete solution. The reason why I do not present a completely automatic solution is that all proposals that I was able to come up with at a given point made use of `transform canvas`. To give you an example, one thing one could imagine to do is to save the path, look how much off it is and then reuse it with [these nice tricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127045/121799). However, I could only shift the reused paths with transform canvas. While that looks visually OK, ultimately this is still problematic since you could not use the shifted path for intersections.

For all these reasons I would like to argue that on the long run this non-automatic solution might be better. It comes with a style

```
determine the necessary shift to=<target>
```

where you feed in your desired center of the curve. If you already sit at the center, the code will remain silent, otherwise it will tell you which `xshift` and `yshift` you need to add such that the centers are at the desired coordinates.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}
\tikzset{determine the necessary shift to/.style={save path=\tmpPath,
preaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.5 with {\coordinate (aux);
\pgftransformreset
\path let \p1=($#1-(aux)$),\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in \pgfextra{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nTest}{\n1}
\ifnum\nTest=0
\else
\typeout{Please\space add\space xshift=\x1,yshift=\y1\space to your path}
\fi};
};}}}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,4);
\draw [thick, green] (1.8,1.4) node [circle, draw, black, fill=black, scale=0.2]{} +(-50:1.4cm) -- +(130:1.4cm);
\draw [thick, orange] (1.4,1.4) node [circle, draw, black, fill=black, scale=0.2]{} +(50:1.4cm) -- +(-130:1.4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,4);
\draw [determine the necessary shift to={(1.8,1.4)},green,thick,xshift=8.24234pt,yshift=1.83932pt] (.88,3.5) to [out=-90,in=180]  +(-46.:4.cm);
\draw [determine the necessary shift to={(1.8,1.4)},thick, blue,xshift=7.93524pt,yshift=-7.4265pt] (.74,.2) to [out=90,in=-90] +(60:3.8cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]