# Modify bounding box to square

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to modify rectangle bounding box to square and plus 10% enlarge! I wish below logic work but error reported:

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %\tikzset{background rectangle/.style={fill=gray!20}, show background rectangle}
    \tikzset{
        save path/.code 2 args={
            \pgfkeysalso{#1/.estyle={insert path={#2}}}%
            \global\expandafter\let\csname pgfk@\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd\expandafter\endcsname
            \csname pgfk@\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd\endcsname
            \pgfkeysalso{#1}%
        }
    }
    \coordinate (O) at (5,5);
    \foreach \i in {30,150,-30,-150} {
        \begin{scope}[rotate around={\i:(O)}]    
            \coordinate (P) at (7.45,5);    
            \begin{scope}[rotate around={180:(P)}]
                \draw[fill=white] (5.65,5) -- ++(1.8,1.5) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(1.8,0) 
                -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(-1.8,0) -- ++(0,-1) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
    }

    \path let \p1=(current bounding box.center),
              \p2=(current bounding box.east),
              \p2=(current bounding box.north),
              \n1={max(\x2-\x1,\y3-\y1)*1.1},
              \x3={x1-\n1},
              \y3={y1-\n1},
              \x4={x1+\n1},
              \y4={y1+\n1}
              in 
              useasboundingbox (\x3,\y3) rectangle (\x4,\y4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@ 

l.30               \n1={max(\x2-\x1,\y3-\y1)*1.1}
                                                 ,
?
```

Comment: I guess you're missing some `\makeatletter`, aren't you?

Comment: Why two `\p2` ? You can't define `\x3` and `\y3` (these values are automatically defined from point `\p3`).

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks,it's really a big problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increase the bounding box, you do not need any of these. Most likely there is a predefined way, but even without opening the pgfmanual you could just do

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (O) at (5,5);
    \foreach \i in {30,150,-30,-150} {
        \begin{scope}[rotate around={\i:(O)}]    
            \coordinate (P) at (7.45,5);    
            \begin{scope}[rotate around={180:(P)}]
                \draw[fill=white] (5.65,5) -- ++(1.8,1.5) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(1.8,0) 
                -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(-1.8,0) -- ++(0,-1) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
    }

    \path (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.north east)
    coordinate[pos=-0.1] (sw) coordinate[pos=1.1] (ne);
    \path[use as bounding box] (sw) rectangle (ne);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Sorry, I did not read carefully enough. Yes, for a quadratic bounding box, `calc` is very handy.

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (O) at (5,5);
    \foreach \i in {30,150,-30,-150} {
        \begin{scope}[rotate around={\i:(O)}]    
            \coordinate (P) at (7.45,5);    
            \begin{scope}[rotate around={180:(P)}]
                \draw[fill=white] (5.65,5) -- ++(1.8,1.5) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(1.8,0) 
                -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(-1.8,0) -- ++(0,-1) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
    }

    \path[use as bounding box] let \p1=(current bounding box.south west),\p2=(current bounding
    box.center) in (\p2) circle ({1.1*max(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why did your code throw errors? You were mixing a few things (as also observed independently by Paul Gaborit), and I fixed them to arrive at

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %\tikzset{background rectangle/.style={fill=gray!20}, show background rectangle}
%     \tikzset{
%         save path/.code 2 args={
%             \pgfkeysalso{#1/.estyle={insert path={#2}}}%
%             \global\expandafter\let\csname pgfk@\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd\expandafter\endcsname
%             \csname pgfk@\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd\endcsname
%             \pgfkeysalso{#1}%
%         }
%     }
    \coordinate (O) at (5,5);
    \foreach \i in {30,150,-30,-150} {
        \begin{scope}[rotate around={\i:(O)}]    
            \coordinate (P) at (7.45,5);    
            \begin{scope}[rotate around={180:(P)}]
                \draw[fill=white] (5.65,5) -- ++(1.8,1.5) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(1.8,0) 
                -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(-1.8,0) -- ++(0,-1) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
    }

    \path let \p1=(current bounding box.center),
              \p2=(current bounding box.east),
              \p3=(current bounding box.north),
              \n1={max(\x2-\x1,\y3-\y1)*1.1},
              \n2={\x1-\n1},
              \n3={\y1-\n1},
              \n4={\x1+\n1},
              \n5={\y1+\n1}
              in 
              [use as bounding box] (\n2,\n3) rectangle (\n4,\n5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I commented out `save path`, as this key is already predefined. What is not predefined (unless you load the `spath3` library) is the `use path` key, which can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127045/121799). (I am not a historian, so I do not know who had it first.) As for your real problem, you cannot assign values to `\x3`, say, only to `\n1`, `\n2` etc. `\x1` and `\y1` are the coordinates of `\p1` and so on.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks, for solution 1,  I prefer square but not rectangle! Not sure how to modify it as a square!

Comment: @lucky1928 Sorry for not reading carefully enough. I added a simple trick for a quadratic box. (As far as the bounding box is concerned, a circle and a square do the same.)

Comment: Good idea, I am curious about your drawing is circle, so I think it should be a circle bounding box, but actually it's a rectange as expected!