# How to fill the area between n intersecting points in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Given two shapes, which are intersecting, how can we fill the area common to them in TikZ (i.e. the area between their intersecting points).

Here, the `even odd rule` might not work as it is not alternate filling but intersecting points.

Please note to determine the intersecting points, I am using the `intersections` library.

In the below MWE, how do I fill the area between `C` and `C'`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,through}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1.25,0.25);


  \node (E) [name path=E,draw,circle through=(B)] at (A) {};
  \node (F) [name path=F,draw,circle through=(A)] at (B) {};

  \path [name intersections={of=E and F, by={[label=above:$C$]C,[label=below:$C'$]C'}}];


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The common area is obtained by clipping against one of the circles and filling the other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,through}
\makeatletter % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127045/121799
\tikzset{use path/.code=\tikz@addmode{\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1.25,0.25);


  \node (E) [name path=E,draw,circle through=(B),save path=\pathA] at (A) {};
  \node (F) [name path=F,draw,circle through=(A),save path=\pathB] at (B) {};
  \begin{scope}
  \clip[use path=\pathA];
  \fill[blue,use path=\pathB];
  \end{scope}

  \path [name intersections={of=E and F, by={[label=above:$C$]C,[label=below:$C'$]C'}}];


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you are concerned by the fact that the circle contour gets partly overpainted, use `backgrounds`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,through,backgrounds}
\makeatletter % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127045/121799
\tikzset{use path/.code=\tikz@addmode{\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1.25,0.25);


  \node (E) [name path=E,draw,circle through=(B),save path=\pathA] at (A) {};
  \node (F) [name path=F,draw,circle through=(A),save path=\pathB] at (B) {};
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \clip[use path=\pathA];
  \fill[blue,use path=\pathB];
  \end{scope}

  \path [name intersections={of=E and F, by={[label=above:$C$]C,[label=below:$C'$]C'}}];


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can always fill intersection segments. (You can combine this with the background stuff above.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1.25,0.25);


  \node (E) [name path=E,draw,circle through=(B)] at (A) {};
  \node (F) [name path=F,draw,circle through=(A)] at (B) {};

  \path [name intersections={of=E and F, by={[label=above:$C$]C,[label=below:$C'$]C'}}];

  \path[%draw,red,thick,
  fill=blue,
  intersection segments={of=E and F,sequence={L1--R2--L3}}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(Same output as above.)

The analytic determination of the arcs is another possibility.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,through,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1.25,0.25);


  \node (E) [name path=E,draw,circle through=(B)] at (A) {};
  \node (F) [name path=F,draw,circle through=(A)] at (B) {};

  \path [name intersections={of=E and F, by={[label=above:$C$]C,[label=below:$C'$]C'}}];
  \path[fill=blue] let \p1=($(A.center)-(B.center)$),\p2=($(C.center)-(A.center)$),
  \p3=($(C'.center)-(A.center)$),\p4=($(C.center)-(B.center)$),
  \p5=($(C'.center)-(B.center)$),
  \n1={veclen(\x2,\y2)}, % radius A
  \n2={veclen(\x4,\y4)}, % radius B
  \n3={atan2(\y2,\x2)}, % angle A 1
  \n4={atan2(\y3,\x3)}, % angle A 2
  \n5={atan2(\y4,\x4)}, % angle B 1
  \n6={atan2(\y5,\x5)} % angle B 2
  in (C) arc(\n3:\n4:\n1)  arc(\n6:\n5-360:\n2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks . Is there alternate to using clipping in TikZ.

Comment: I feel clipping might not be a generic solution to the requirement.  As mentioned in the question , the area can be anything between the n points.  Is there a generic approach to solve this apart from clipping.

Comment: Analytic determination of arcs will be tedious.  Can you please elaborate the `pgfplots` solution as well

Comment: @subhamsoni OK, I added the fillbetween stuff.

Comment: Can you please explain the parameter compat here

Comment: @subhamsoni `pgfplots` has a very careful version management, so `compat=1.16` indicates that version 1.16 is to be used. Almost certainly this has no effect here. However, I follow the practice to indicate the version because there are cases where that matters.

Comment: Thanks marmot.  The answer and explanation is quite helpful